# Retrieving all events in a month with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've been scouring the Google Apps Script documentation for a way to retrieve all events in the current month that the script is ran in. Let me give some background on what I'm trying to do:

I have a reoccurring event in a Google Calendar that repeats every two weeks on Friday. This event signifies when my company has a payday. As you might expect, this event happens at least twice a month on two different dates. I'm trying to find the two dates that are paydays in the current month.

I figured I could try to find all events in a month and then try to sort and find the two payday events from there, but I can't find a single function that returns events for the current month.

How might I go about getting this information?

Answer (score 5):

I was thinking about this too hard. Here was my solution:

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(firstDay, lastDay, {search: 'Payday'});
Logger.log('Number of paydays: ' + events.length);
Logger.log('First payday is: ' + events[0].getStartTime().toISOString());
```